# Updating resque workers with new code without terminating them

Tags: resque

Say that we change the code for one of our Resque workers. How can we deploy that code to the workers, short of stopping the workers in the middle of the task (thereby removing the task from the queue forever and with it not being finished) and reloading the worker?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ended up simply killing the workers.

Comment: @Luccas you can find the pid of the resque process with this command `ps ax | grep resque`